# How to find out what wireless card is installed in computer?

Tags: windows-xp, wireless-networking

I can't open my desktop to see what wireless card is installed in it.

And WinXP doesn't recognized it.

How can I find out manufacture and model of card?

Comment: First, if you can't get inside the desktop, you need to state that.  Have you considered booting from a Linux CD?  Maybe Linux has the drivers to work with it.  Then you'll at least be able to discover the chip set.

Comment: Than you for editing your comment to include that information.

Answer (score 2):

I like using [SIW](http://www.gtopala.com/) (System Information for Windows) for this sometimes.

Answer (score 2):

Try [speccy](http://www.piriform.com/speccy)

From website:

> Speccy will give you detailed statistics on every piece of hardware in your computer. Including CPU, Motherboard, RAM, Graphics Cards, Hard Disks, Optical Drives, Audio support. Additionally Speccy adds the temperatures of your different components, so you can easily see if there's a problem!

I have also found [Unknown device Identifier](http://www.zhangduo.com/udi.html).  I have not used this software but appears to be doing what you are looking for:

> Unknown Device Identifier enables you to identify the yellow question mark labeled Unknown Devices in Device Manager. And reports you a detailed summary for the manufacturer name, OEM name, device type, device model and even the exact name of the unknown devices.

Answer (score 1):

I would take the model number or even the part number of the laptop and look up specs on it. There you could easily find the make and model of the wireless card.

Comment: it's a desktop...

Comment: You didn't mention that you couldn't open the desktop and look inside of it.  If Windows XP doesn't recognize the device, the OS can't tell you anything about it.  If you can't open the desktop and look inside, maybe a magic 8 ball would help?

Comment: May be some sorf of software?

Comment: You could still do this for a desktop. Why do you think you couldn't? Anyways, it takes about as much effort to open it up and look yourself than it does to find the model number and Google it...

Comment: Who -1 -ed me? Obviously someone who doesn't know much about computers... My answer is completely legitimate, and if it isn't than I guess my whole career is a lie... Give a reason if your going to -1 someone please.

Comment: David, I brought you back up to 0 because I knew your answer was accurate.  I'm guessing you got -1 because you didn't know the user couldn't open their computer.  Notice that information changed in the original posting.

Comment: Thanks for bringing me back up. I noticed that. I really appreciate it. Some people need to know that people edit their answers and read comments.

Comment: I -1 you due to the fact that the OP stated he comp wasn't able to be opened.  Edits haven't been made to the question (you can see previous edits when made).  Finally getting a -1 isn't that big of a deal.

Comment: No... but I like to understand why. I don't know why you would,'t want to learn from your mistakes.

Comment: Also, just because he can't open the machine doesn't mean he can't see the model number on the back of the desktop or on the bottom. Normally they will have the model number on there.

Comment: Not all PC's are bought from major corp and are homemade.  A model number would not be helpful in this case

Comment: He didn't mention if it was home made did he? As far as I am concerned it is fair game.

Comment: It's homemade. And it's not a game. I have just opened case but card is in the last slot. And I can't see the model name. I don't want to take the dusty card out if it is an easy way to find out it's model. Only I know now is that it's D-Link.

Comment: Kronos, a model number from the card could be INCREDIBLY helpful.  And if it's a U.S. manufacturer there will be an FCC ID on a sticker on the card.  These could be very helpful things.